# Cassandra replication factor: need to node to have complete data for reporting

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have CassandraDB running for an application with replication factor three per data center. Each data center has 5 nodes each.

- I need a dedicated node for reporting purposes which has the complete data. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, you can create one new node in its own logical "reporting" data center.  This can be done by editing the `dc` line in your cassandra-rackdc.properties file.  Ex:

```
dc=east_dc_reporting
```

Then when you alter your keysapce, you'll set that DC with a RF of 1:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE stackoverflow WITH replication =
  {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
   'west_dc': '3',
   'east_dc': '3',
   'east_dc_reporting': '1'};
```

That should work, assuming that you built your node with enough disk to hold your complete data set.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'll give it a try